# GET request for CSRF not

Tags: javascript, reactjs, httprequest, csrf

In my project for back-end I have `laravel` and for front-end I use `react-js`
I want to make a get request for CSRF token, on my localhost but the token is not there
this is my postman request
[postman Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGAKt.png) and this is the response [postman response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5mwJ.png)
this is my code for `GET request`

```
const getCSRF = async () => {
    const temp = await fetch(`${BaseURL}/csrf`, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers : { 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'accept':'application/json'
       }
    })
    .then((response) => console.log("CSRF response",response))
}
```

the console view is [Console view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/125n9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, all data fetch request is a `GET` request and you don't need to pass headers, you just need to convert the response to text(`response.text()`)(as we can see in Postman response)

```
const getCSRF = async () => {
    const temp = await fetch(`${BaseURL}/csrf`)
                  .then(response => console.log("CSRF response", response.text()))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what was wrong but I use axios like this and it's working

```
axios.get(`${BaseURL}/csrf`) 
    .then(res => {
    console.log("CSRF response",res)
})
```